# How to delay a component's unmount event in pure ReactJS (without React Router)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using only ReactJS and no other dependencies, how can we delay a component's unmount event in the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method?

I'm looking to add, for example, a `500ms` delay so that an animation could play before a component unmounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with React Transition Group:
https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, tying side-effects to `componenWillUnmount` although attractive at first glance, never works perfectly.

You can achieve that changing another property to start the exit transition and check that change in `componentWillReceiveProps`. Then you can add the `500ms` delay and continue to unmount.

Check this [post](https://medium.com/@tomaszferens/delay-unmounting-of-the-component-in-react-8d6f6e73cdc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop to block the umounting until a condition is met.

```js
    componentWillUnmount() {
        const timeout = new Date().getTime() + 500;
    
        //Do your 500ms animation here
    
        while (new Date().getTime() < timeout) {}
    }
```